# How can I detect if nothing is selected in MySql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I was working on simple command which checks if there is a specific data in MySql table. First, I tried `console.log(result)`:

```js
const checksql = "SELECT * FROM web_editor_data where name='somename'";
connection.query(checksql, (err, result, fields) => {
  console.log(checksql);
}
```

It logged `[]`.
Therefore, I tried:

```js
const checksql = "SELECT * FROM web_editor_data where name='somename'";
connection.query(checksql, (err, result, fields) => {
  console.log(checksql == []);
}
```

However, it logged `false`.
Is there anything wrong with my code? Or is there a more effective alternative for this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `result.length === 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
checksql == []
```

This is a great guess, unfortunately in Javascript when comparing arrays and objects, they are not compared by value (what they contain) but if the are literally the same thing.

So `checksql` is only identical to `checksql`, which is why this doesn't work. `[]` is a different array, and if you add an item to `[]` it doesn't automatically get added to `checksql` too.

The typical way to just see if something is empty, is by counting the number of items.

You can do this with the length property:

```
checksql.length === 0; // If true, array is empty
```